# Recursion error in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow

I am, sometimes, getting an recursion error on this code.

Can somebody tell me why?

What i am trying to make is just autoplay in Tic Tac Toe.
Nothing fancy. Just learning.

```
 private void Auto_play()
    {
        try
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int d = rnd.Next(0, 9);
            label3.Text = d.ToString();

            if (d == 0 && A1.Enabled)
                A1.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 1 && A2.Enabled)
                A2.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 2 && A3.Enabled)
                A3.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 3 && B1.Enabled)
                B1.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 4 && B2.Enabled)
                B2.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 5 && B3.Enabled)
                B3.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 6 && C1.Enabled)
                C1.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 7 && C2.Enabled)
                C2.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 8 && C3.Enabled)
                C3.PerformClick();
            else
                Auto_play();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by 'recursion error'.  Do you mean that the program unexpectedly stops, or it continues in an endless loop?  Is it consistently after x number of moves, or entirely random?  If it is a crash, try catching the exception and reading the message  `catch (Exception ex) { string err = ex.Message;}`

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: Make sure you do not have an infinite loop or recursion.

Comment: Sorry about the messy input. Trying to figure out this website :-)

Comment: Presumably, your `PerformClick()` doesn't end the game when it's supposed to, and that means that this code calls itself infinitely.  Please show the code for `PeformClick()` (or the event handler).

Answer (score 2):

Doing recursion via calling the same method you are already in is a bad idea, because you will get a stack overflow quite quickly. Depending on what is already loaded, you could end up crashing within a couple hundred iterations.

The fix is to not call the method from within itself. Instead, you keep track of the work you need to do and loop until you have no more work to do. Something like this:

```
Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
queue.Enque(startingValue);

while (queue.Any())
{
    string val = queue.Deque();
    // work with string
    queue.Enque("new string found to do additional work with");
}
```

That is actually what I use if I need to recurse through directories or something similar, however yours is a simpler case. I'm thinking it could be solved with something like this:

```
private void Auto_play()
{
    try
    {
        bool foundMove = false;

        while (!foundMove)
        {
            foundMove = true;

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int d = rnd.Next(0, 9);
            label3.Text = d.ToString();

            if (d == 0 && A1.Enabled)
                A1.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 1 && A2.Enabled)
                A2.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 2 && A3.Enabled)
                A3.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 3 && B1.Enabled)
                B1.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 4 && B2.Enabled)
                B2.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 5 && B3.Enabled)
                B3.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 6 && C1.Enabled)
                C1.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 7 && C2.Enabled)
                C2.PerformClick();
            else if (d == 8 && C3.Enabled)
                C3.PerformClick();
            else
                foundMove = false;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

A side note for interest sake: `Random` is not very random. And you might even find you keep replaying the same game or set of games over and over (if you tracked them somewhere). Getting a truly random number with a computer is <strike>hard</strike> impossible, but that is a subject that much has already been written on.

**Update:**
As Nate M. points out: the above code is rough still and not actually complete. You could still get into an endless loop due to a number of conditions:

1. The game has ended and this method is called (i.e. no more valid move locations).
2. The Random call keeps giving the same number or set of numbers.
3. There is probably another one or two I'm missing... :)

Comment: I was about to say, I think recursion could be eliminated entirely.  An additional improvement may be to iterate until a valid cell is found also, then you would run a single pass and rely on a single random seed rather than multiple.  You still have the 'possibility' of an endless loop with the code listed above (albeit unlikely)

Comment: Good point @NateM. I added an update to note the possibility!

Comment: To follow up...i check for winner elsewhere. I remember something like Randomice. Something based  on time and date. i'snt that around anymore?